# Serialization and permissions in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm new in Django and DRF, have questions with serialization.
I have models:

```
class Commodity(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Clother(models.Model):
    commodity = models.ForeignKey(Commodity, related_name='commodity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color, related_name='color')
    material = models.ManyToManyField(Material, related_name='material')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=UNISEX)

class Outwear(models.Model):
    clother = models.ForeignKey(Clother, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    outwear_type = models.ForeignKey(OutwearType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(ClotherSize)
```

So I suppose to make a Serializer like that:

```
class OutwearSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    commodity = CommoditySerializer(many=False, read_only=False)
    clother = ClotherSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Outwear
        fields = ('commodity', 'clother', 'name', 'outwear_type', 'size')
```

As I understand that read_only fields let me add or edit Outwear object further, but I supposed to have 2 types of permition:

1. All users can see only active Commodity objects.
2. Only Companies can create and edit their own objects.

Do I need to make 2 Serializer Models for `read_only=True/False`?
What is the best practice and where can I find good examples of something familiar? 
I call User - unauthorized User. Company is authorized User.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain about user roles? Are company and user different model??

Comment: @MohammadAli edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

```
class CommoditySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Commodity
        fields = (shop, price)


Class CommodityActiveAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CommoditySerializer
    queryset = Commodity.objects.filter(active=True)
```

second question is ambiguous. first define user role please

Comment: This View shows all active Commodities to all users. I need to make all users can only read active Commodities. And also let Companies create new Commodities and edit Commodities created by them. Thanks!

Comment: your authentication is with user not company. you should have role for user model. then create a permission class . in this class you can say if user is company can create or edit commodity